# Java Replace specific number in String using .replace(x,y)?

Tags: java, string

Is it possible to replace a specific number in a String by using:

```
string.replace(4 + "", "FOUR");
```

I have tried doing this, and it does not seem to work. Is there a dynamic way to do this that lets me use an Integer?

Here is the code:

```
public void generateData(String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
        text.replace(array.get(i).number, "HELLO WORLD");
    }
    System.out.println("T: " + text);
}
```

When I print it, I get something like this:

```
10014001261627161
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Can you give a sample input and the output you are getting?

Comment: You need to replace it as a character. `String.replace(""+4, "FOUR") should work, if you don't want to explicitly typecast it.

Comment: @AaronD, is it different from what he already has? I think changing the order here shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Why not just use `"4"`?

Comment: @Codebender, yes, `""+4` leads to the integer `4` being implicitly typecast as a String. It is equivalent to calling `Integer.toString(4)`, although that form would be preferred as it is explicit. `4+""` would lead to an error as it is trying to add the empty string to an int.

Comment: @Andreas the value is dynamic. So I just used that to cast it to a String.

Comment: @AaronD, I don't think so. Did you try it?

Comment: OH wow. Sorry everyone. look at this: text.replace. I should say: text = text.replace... I need some sleep

Comment: @Codebender - you are right. I did just check and the implicit cast works either way. My mistake!

Comment: @TastyLemons I think using `int + ""` (or `"" + int`) is lazy, and generates inefficient code. Use `Integer.toString(int)` to use explicit type, or `String.valueOf(int)` to allow compiler to choose the right overload.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine, in all forms.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(4, "FOUR", "");
    test(4, "FOUR", "Hello");
    test(4, "FOUR", "4");
    test(4, "FOUR", "1 2 3 4 5 6");
    test(4, "FOUR", "123456");
    test(4, "FOUR", "Test43");
}
private static void test(int num, String numText, String string) {
    System.out.println("\"" + string + "\" -> \"" + string.replace(num + "", numText) + "\"" +
                                          " = \"" + string.replace("" + num, numText) + "\"" +
                                          " = \"" + string.replace(String.valueOf(num), numText) + "\"");
}
```

Output is:

```
"" -> "" = "" = ""
"Hello" -> "Hello" = "Hello" = "Hello"
"4" -> "FOUR" = "FOUR" = "FOUR"
"1 2 3 4 5 6" -> "1 2 3 FOUR 5 6" = "1 2 3 FOUR 5 6" = "1 2 3 FOUR 5 6"
"123456" -> "123FOUR56" = "123FOUR56" = "123FOUR56"
"Test43" -> "TestFOUR3" = "TestFOUR3" = "TestFOUR3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `int` to a `String`, as `String.replace()` expects either a `char` or a `CharSequence` (which is a superclass of `String`). It will **not** accept an `int` argument.

The most explicit way to do what you are asking is to cast using `Integer.toString()`. Like so:

```
public void generateData(String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
        text=text.replace(Integer.toString(array.get(i).number), "HELLO WORLD");
    }
    System.out.println("T: " + text);
}
```